# How do I remove a node with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

How can I remove `<img>` tags using Nokogiri?

I have the following code but it wont work:

```
# str = '<img src="canadascapital.gc.ca/data/2/rec_imgs/5005_Pepsi_H1NB.gif"/…; testt<a href="#">test</a>tfbu' 

f = Nokogiri::XML.fragment(str)
f.search('//img').each do |node| 
  node.remove
end
puts f
```

Comment: Can you post a sample value for `str`?

Comment: str = '<img src="http://www.canadascapital.gc.ca/data/2/rec_imgs/5005_Pepsi_H1NB.gif"/> testt<a href="#">test</a>tfbu'

Comment: added that to the question..  next time just edit the question to add the information asked for, much easier than having to assemble stuff out of the question plus comments.

Comment: I needed to remove all the scripts on a page $page_html = Nokogiri::HTML.parse($browser.html) ; $page_html.search('//script').each{|x| x.remove} ; # worked like a charm. ty

Answer (score 87, accepted):

have a try!

```
f = Nokogiri::XML.fragment(str)

f.search('.//img').remove
puts f
```

Answer (score 17):

I prefer CSS over XPath, as it's usually much more readable. Switching to CSS:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<html><body><img src="foo"><img src="bar"></body></html>')
```

After parsing the document looks like:

```
doc.to_html
# => "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html><body>\n<img src=\"foo\"><img src=\"bar\">\n</body></html>\n"
```

Removing the `<img>` tags:

```
doc.search('img').each do |src|
  src.remove
end
```

Results in:

```
doc.to_html
# => "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html><body></body></html>\n"
```

Comment: Since your block is just calling a method on each iterable, if you want to be fancy you can do symbol to proc: `doc.search('img').each(&:remove)`.

Comment: Yes, but back then, in 2013, we didn't have that fancy ability.

Comment: I'm from the future! :) Thanks for this answer. This one and others of yours have been helping me a lot as I'm making Ruby scripts to change large batches of HTML files and automate myself out of a (menial component of my) job.

Comment: It's nice to know the answers help; That's the whole point of SO, teaching and passing on what we've learned.