# Remove Certain HTML Tags using Ruby

Tags: html, ruby, regex, html-parsing

How can I remove certain HTML tags by name in Ruby?

For example:

```
string = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>My First Heading</h1><p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>"

string.magic_method("h1") #=> "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>"
```

I wrote some regex to do this but wondered if there was a library or native method that could do the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [**Nokogiri**](http://nokogiri.org/):

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML <<-_HTML_
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>My First Heading</h1><p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>
_HTML_

doc.at('h1')
# => #(Element:0x4d2f006 {
#      name = "h1",
#      children = [ #(Text "My First Heading")]
#      })

doc.at('h1').unlink
puts doc.to_html
# >> <!DOCTYPE html>
# >> <html><body><p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the gem `nokogiri`. It has some nice methods to manipulate HTML and XML, including one that removes tags as you can see here: [How do I remove a node with Nokogiri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708504/how-do-i-remove-a-node-with-nokogiri)

Github: https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri