# Using nokogiri how do I remove all elements with a certain classname

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm experimenting with Ruby and Nokogiri.

I've figured out how to open a local html document and select nodes by classname:

```
require 'rubygems'                                                                                               
require 'nokogiri'                                                                                               

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("file"))                                                                          


puts doc.css('a.target')
```

How then do I dump the document *without* the nodes I've selected for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a node with Nokogiri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708504/how-do-i-remove-a-node-with-nokogiri)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be:

```
doc.css('a.target').remove
puts doc.at('html').to_s
```